# Avoiding extra printing when counting characters in a string

Tags: arrays, c, for-loop, while-loop, char

For my CS class we have to code in C the following program:

For a txt file, count how many letters of the alphabet begin each word of the file.
For example:

- t is used 5 times at the beginning of a word
- e is used 4 times at the beginning of a word
- etc

The code I wrote does meet this but my method does this each time with each letter even if we have already counted it, I've included in it some way to sort of numb this down but it doesn't work, it just counts them less times.

Can anyone give me an idea to fix this?
How should I approach it?
I tried removing said character after reading but I just end up erasing the entire string instead.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#define SIZE 64
#define LINES 64
#define file_location "text.txt"
int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    char text[SIZE][LINES];
    char text_buff[SIZE+2];
    char word_arr[SIZE];
    int line_counter=0;
    
    
    
    FILE* file;
    file = fopen(file_location, "r");
    
    while(fgets(text_buff, SIZE, file)){
        text_buff[(strlen(text_buff)-1)]='\0';
        
        strcpy( text[line_counter],text_buff);
        line_counter++;
    }
    
    int i=0;
    printf("the file read is:\n");
    
    while(text[i][0]!='\0'){
        printf("%s\n",text[i]);
        i++;
        
    }
    int counter=0;
    
    for (int i=0; i<line_counter; i++) {
        for (int j=0; j<strlen(text[i]); j++) {
            if(isalpha(text[i][j]) && !isalpha(text[i][j-1])){
                word_arr[counter]=text[i][j];
                counter++;
            }
            
        }
    }
    printf("the letters starting each word are:\n");
    
    puts(word_arr);
    
    char reg[strlen(word_arr)];
    
    for (int i=0; i<strlen(word_arr); i++) {
        int counter_c=0;
        char buf = word_arr[i];
        for (int j=0; j< strlen(word_arr); j++) {
            if(buf == word_arr[j] && buf != reg[j]){
                counter_c++;
            }
        }
        int flag=1;
        
        for (int k=0; k<strlen(word_arr); k++) {
            if(reg[i]==buf){
                flag=0;
            }
        }
        
        if(flag==1){
          printf("%c has been used to start a word %d times\n",buf,counter_c);
        }
        
        reg[i]=buf;
    }
        
        
    

   
    
  
    
    
    
    return 0;
}
```

The output is:

```
t has been used to start a word 6 times
i has been used to start a word 1 times
a has been used to start a word 1 times
f has been used to start a word 3 times
f has been used to start a word 2 times
c has been used to start a word 1 times
t has been used to start a word 5 times
p has been used to start a word 1 times
t has been used to start a word 4 times
w has been used to start a word 2 times
n has been used to start a word 1 times
t has been used to start a word 3 times
w has been used to start a word 1 times
f has been used to start a word 1 times
t has been used to start a word 2 times
e has been used to start a word 1 times
o has been used to start a word 1 times
J has been used to start a word 1 times
t has been used to start a word 1 times
```

Comment: Sounds like you want to keep all of your individual counters (one for each letter) going at once, collected in some structure you could index by the character itself.

Comment: I think you can make an integer array and keep track of which all are already done. Maybe a simple array for each letter, initialize each to 0 and then compare if the values non-zero, if non-zero, then  no need of printing.

Comment: Yeah I tried that originally but I must've committed some mistakes because it wasn't working, I tried it again with a different approach and now it worked, thank you !

Answer (score 3):

You should probably do something like this semipseudo:

```
int histogram['z'-'a'+1] = {0}; // Room for whole alphabet

for each word in file: 
    histogram[lowercase(word[0]) - 'a']++;
```

After this, `histogram['t'-'a']` will contain the number of words that starts with `t` or `T`.

Comment: A possible suggestion to single out each individual word is to use the `strtok()` function from `string.h`. See this [link](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_strtok.htm) for an explaination, in particular check out the example.

Comment: I actually ended up doing what all of you guys suggested to practice a bit more! Thank you guys!